# how to make apk for only tv and box android

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, tvbox

I developed a small application (video player) on android studio
my question and the following "how can I make the application executable on android tv and android box only?"
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To limit device compatibility, make sure you have the following in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
```

This will limit it to Android TV devices, and then you can manually limit from there as needed.